# Why is Magento 2 using the old jQuery 1?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, jquery

I opened the developer console and executed `jQuery.fn.jquery` and I get **1.12.4**.

Why does Magento 2 uses that old version, even though the latest version is 3.4.1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cause this can breaks some core functionality
Default used jquery 1.12.4 but in future i believe they will migrate it to higher stable. 
But you can remove default and load new version of jquery in your site but possible introduced some breaks

Comment: ok lol... jQuery 1.1 was released in January 14, 2007... and Magento 2 was released in 17. November 2015. I guess they started developing it back then.